# OOP PHP Confusion, transition from procedural to OO PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm very new to PHP so far and have been trying to learn it. A big difficulty I face though is I just can't bend my head around to think about how is a PHP website structured with classes, objects, namespaces.

I'm not entirely new to OOP as I do have a little experience in Python and Java but PHP OOP just got me stumped. Many of the newbie PHP books I saw were on procedural PHP. I followed them made 1--2 small website but when I got to OOP, I'm just stuck and any tips on how you made the transition from procedural to OO PHP would be appreciated. In particular these are the questions on my mind at this moment

1. What are the type of classes one would usually creates? I thought of giving a class for each table in my database (User, Book) as well as maybe a form class, are there any other type of candidates that could be turned into classes too?
2. Any other way to reduce html code duplication other than the old usual require() and include()?
3. Any recommended ways to structure a typical PHP website? I currently only knows of having a folder for includes file. But I would like to know more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have questions, here are my answers!

1. The classes you make in PHP can be related to objects like User, Book as you would do in a persistent program.  If you look at a framework like [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) you can make a class as specific as constructing database queries to a class that uses an MVC architecture consisting of multiple classes to render your entire website.
2. To reduce code duplication, you can, for example, write a class to construct a table (or if you are really fancy a div table maker.).  Then you can write methods like makeRow(), makeDivision(), etc... get really fancy and then you can write clean PHP code that can generate really large powerful pages.

   **EDIT**:
   If you were talking about reducing about the amount of include you'd have to do for classes then yes, [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) on the PHP website is something you will want to look at!
3. Structure of your website can be based on the model you want to use.  Right now it seems that [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) models are popular with frameworks, but it is up to you how your want your web app to be made.  I'm sure you can take any architecture model and base your website around it. 

   With all that said, if you don't feel like start from absolute scratch on your project there are a plethora of PHP frameworks to choose from:

   [Comparison of Web application frameworks: PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks#PHP) via Wikipedia

Comment: +1 for being the answer which in my opinion has the most sensible approach to answering this question. No experience with CodeIgniter myself, but I too would recommend looking at some MVC frameworks (Zend Framework is my choice, although it could be a bit complex for absolute OOP beginners)

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting question that brings us back to the age-old debate of procedural vs. OO programming.  Why pick one or the other?  The answer is..nobody has one.  The whole purpose of designing software is to get something done.  Does it matter how you get there?  Well, it depends.  If you get there very sloppily and a lot of updates are required, that's a big waste of time.  Does OO programming prevent this?  Absolutely not.

It seems like your real question is how to integrate OO into a website.  This is really not something that you should do for the heck of it.  What are you trying to achieve with this website?  Does it contain many different application states with user interaction in a FSM or is it just a bunch of static pages.  How much information do these pages share?

Let's tackle your specific questions first:

1. What type of classes does one usually create?  Whatever type of classes they want!  Before you type one character of code, you should sit down and write out a design for your application.  No one can tell you how to do this: write up some documentation, pseudo-code (even in php if you like), draw up a UML diagram, etc.  Figure out how your application can be compartmentalized. Do not make the mistake of dividing up object based on their logical separation in the real world (User, Book) unless it makes sense to.  Why do you need a Book object?  How does it interact with a user?

You could build a very simple class to display your standard webpage:

```
class anypage {
   public function header() {
      return '<head></head>';
   }
   public function footer() {
      return '<br />Copyright &copy; ' . date('Y');
   }
   public function render($body) {
      return '<html>' . $this->header() . "<body>$body{$this->footer()}</body></html>";
   }
}
```

Then on any page call:

```
$page = anypage;
echo $page->render("My Page Content");
```

Anyway, I'm talking more about general OO principles than just PHP, but this is a question that can't be answered.  You design classes that your application needs to get the job done.  A good example of using an object in PHP is [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/), a template language.  Your webpage may look like this:

```
$page = new PHPTAL('mytemplate.xhtml');
echo $page->execute();
```

The PHPTAL class takes care of building the html from your template file.  That's an example of what an object might be used for.

Of course, PHPTAL is huge, and it's broken down into a lot of compartments.  Taking a look at the source code, we see the classes Attr, Element, Node .. these are all pieces of an xml document and they have a class representing them.

An important part of OOP is having objects work together.  Each object should serve a purpose and do what it is good at.  I don't like objects that are models for nouns like "User" or "Book," unless they do something.  PHPTAL does a great job of rendering a view for your page, but how do you know which page to render?  You can use an object to handle that:

```
class controller {
   public function __call($_, $_) { return $this->hello(); }
   public function hello() {
      session_start();
      $view = new PHPTAL('hello.xhtml');
      return $view->execute();
   }
   public function goodbye() {
      session_destroy();
      $_SESSION = array();
      $view = new PHPTAL('goodbye.xhtml');
      return $view->execute();
   }
}
```

On you main page, you would have:

```
$c = new controller;
echo $c->$_REQUEST['action']();
```

If the 'action' is set by the request, the controller responds accordingly by calling that action.  `hello` is used by default thanks to magical `__call()`.

Similar to the other OO languages you are familiar with, you can even have events in PHP:

```
class controller {
   private $models = array();
   private $_listeners = array();
   public function __construct() {
      $model = new model;
      $this->models[] = $model;
      $this->_listeners[] = $model;
   }

   public function action($action = 'hello', $events = array()) {
      $this->$action();
      foreach ($events as $type => $data) {
         foreach ($this->_listeners as $listener) {
            $event = "fire_" . $type;
            $listener->$event($data);
         }
      }
   }
}

class model {
   public function fire_hello($name) {
      echo 'hello ' . $name;
   }
}
```

As other answers have suggested, a good start is to take a look at a PHP framework.  I recommend [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/), since it is a good OO framework.  I'm not necessarily suggesting you build a website from it, but take a look at the documentation and code to get a better understanding of OO development for PHP.

2 [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/) or another templating engine is an awesome way to reduce html duplication.  Even my miniature `anypage` class above is an example.  You don't necessarily have to have an html file and then use `require()` `include()` or `virtual()` to pass it into your code for reuse.  Instead, you can have a wrapper that stores and builds common template html.  I cannot stress enough how much I love PHPTAL for this purpose.  XSLT is an alternative.

3 There is no set way to do this.  Others are suggesting "Use a framework."  I don't necessarily disagree.  Using a framework helps out a lot in taking care of some of the annoying business of setting things up.  It's not a magic problem-solving placebo, but it is nice for some things.  If you are just trying to learn and there is no constraint on time, I say write your own framework.  That will definitely teach you about OO programming in PHP.  If time is a concern, use one of the 500,000 frameworks out there that others are suggesting.  As for how to structure your website, I tend to have a _js folder for javascript and a _stylesheets folder for stylesheets.  All of the php and xhtml template files I use are just placed in the folders they belong to logically.  It's not rocket science, it's software engineering!

Answer (score 1):

The MVC pattern is essentially the de facto pattern for web apps, regardless of language.  Several frameworks utilize this pattern, including Zend Framework, CodeIgniter, and Kohana.

Like the others have said, __autoload() or spl_autoload_register() is the way to go when it comes to eliminating the need to follow includes/requires.

Remember that the currency of OOP is **objects**.  You're not gaining much if you simply turn some back end data into OO models and calling it a day.  I suggest you look at Matt Zandstra's book *PHP 5: Objects, Patterns, and Practice* as well as the Gang of Four's *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* to really see how to use objects throughout a project.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that working within a framework means that you're only creating some of the components yourself and that there are plenty of examples of best practice.

I moved from procedural stuff to [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) which is a great framework and includes a full MVC model which helps to clearly define what your different objects should do and how they all fit together.

It's likely to be a bit of a learning curve but after a while it makes so much more sense than procedural stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Use an object-oriented MVC framework like CodeIgniter (which is very easy), Yii (bit harder), or CakePHP or Symfony (much harder). You can see how the different objects link to each other, and the benefits from using them.

A good example of classes is the interaction between 'Form', 'Validation' and 'Schema'. You can instantiate a form by passing it a schema, and then use methods in 'Form' to generate HTML without writing it over and over again. When a user submits the form, you validate each field using an instantiation of the 'Validation' class, and then write it to the database using a 'Model'. Each table in your database has a 'Model' which defines how data is written to and retrieved from the database (CRUD).

You can avoid using lots of requires and includes using '__autoload()'.

Comment: Putting CakePHP in the same level of difficulty than Symfony seems odd to me. Especially if the term is "much harder" than the others.

Comment: Sorry, that is a personal opinion rather than an absolute fact. However, I did find it took longer to work out what CakePHP and Symfony are doing because they are both doing a lot more than CodeIgniter and Yii. I use all 4 in different situations, so it's no comment on which one is a 'better' framework.

Comment: I know :) I think they are "harder" than the other two as well. But after using CakePHP and Symfony, Symfony seems even much harder than CakePHP. Too complex in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on what you want to accomplish. In a relatively complex web application you could follow a typical [MVC approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). In that scenario you can create at least two classes, one for the model and one for the controller. And then have several templates (plain PHP files) whose content are filled/completed by the controller. You can create more classes (forms, utilities, code-generators,..) as needed, but be careful to keep your code compact and easy to mantain.
2. Many frameworks rely on the `__autoload()` magic method. Another alternative is to build your mechanism to handle all this stuff, probably using an `AutoLoader` class.
3. Use a framework. Seriously. Or at least take a framework as an example. I recommend [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) due to their fil structure simplicity.